# How can I change the positions of these two lines in my console

Tags: c++

I have to make an ASCII flower for a project of mine. However I am having trouble on one tiny problem before making everything look even. Here is my output

[image]

..and here is what it needs to look like. I know mine is not centered, I would also like some advice on that if possible.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZCcc.png)

Here is my code. The part that SHOULD output the row below the one with the @ symbol are lines 114-128, the sections commented off as 'sectAfter@'.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
// display the prompt to the user
cout << "Program 1: ASCII Flowers\n"
     << "Choose from the following options:\n"
     << "   1. Display the HELLO graphic\n"
     << "   2. Display The Flower\n"
     << "   3. Exit the program\n"
     << "Your choice -> ";

// read in the user's choice
int menu_option;
cin >> menu_option;

// handle option to quit
if (menu_option == 3) {
    exit(0);
}

// handle the HELLO graphic choice
if (menu_option == 1) {
    char frame;
    cout << "Enter your frame character: ";
    cin >> frame;
    //top border
    cout << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
        cout << setfill(frame) << setw(36) << ' ' << endl;
    }
    //message
    cout << setfill(frame) << setw(3) << right << " "
         << "** ** ***** **    **    *****"
         << setfill(frame) << setw(3) << left << " " << endl
         << setfill(frame) << setw(3) << right << " "
         << "** ** ***** **    **    *****"
         << setfill(frame) << setw(3) << left << " " << endl
         << setfill(frame) << setw(3) << right << " "
         << "** ** **    **    **    ** **"
         << setfill(frame) << setw(3) << left << " " << endl
         << setfill(frame) << setw(3) << right << " "
         << "***** ***** **    **    ** **"
         << setfill(frame) << setw(3) << left << " " << endl
         << setfill(frame) << setw(3) << right << " "
         << "***** ***** **    **    ** **"
         << setfill(frame) << setw(3) << left << " " << endl
         << setfill(frame) << setw(3) << right << " "
         << "** ** **    **    **    ** **"
         << setfill(frame) << setw(3) << left << " " << endl
         << setfill(frame) << setw(3) << right << " "
         << "** ** ***** ***** ***** *****"
         << setfill(frame) << setw(3) << left << " " << endl
         << setfill(frame) << setw(3) << right << " "
         << "** ** ***** ***** ***** *****"
         << setfill(frame) << setw(3) << left << " " << endl
         << right;
    //bottom border
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
        cout << setfill(frame) << setw(36) << " " << endl;
    }
}

// 
if (menu_option == 2) {
  cout << "Enter number of sections: ";
  int sectionChoice;
  cin >> sectionChoice;
  
  for (int i = 0; i < sectionChoice; i++) {

    //topDashes
    for (int k = 0; k < sectionChoice; k++) {
      cout << " "; //<< "---" << endl;
    }
    cout << "---" << endl;

    //sectBefore@
    for (int h = 0; h < i; h++) {          
        for (int r = 0; r < (2 * h + 3) ; r++) {              
          if (r == 0) {
            cout << "{";                
          }
          cout << ":"; 
          if (r == (2 * h + 3) - 1) {
            cout << "}" << endl;                
          }             
      }          
    }

    //midWith@ 
    cout << "{";
    for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
      cout << ":";        
    }
    cout << "@";
    for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
      cout << ":";        
    }
    cout << "}" << endl;

    //sectAfter@        
    for (int h = 0; h < i; h++) {
      
      for (int r = 0; r < 2 * h +3; r++) {
          
        if (r == 0) {
          cout << "{";                
        }
        cout << ":"; 
        if (r == (2 * h +3) - 1) {
          cout << "}" << endl;                
        }
          
      }          
    }
  }

    //bottomDashes
    for (int k = 0; k < sectionChoice; k++) {
      cout << " "; 
    }
    cout << "---" << endl;
  
  //stem
    for (int s = 0; s < sectionChoice * 2; s++) {  
      if (s % 2 != 0) {
        cout << setw(sectionChoice + 2) << "|" << endl;
      }
      else if (s % 2 == 0) {
        if (s % 4 == 2) {
          cout << setw(sectionChoice + 1) << "\\" << "|" << endl;
        } else {
          cout << setw(sectionChoice + 2) << "|" << "/" << endl;
        }
      }
      }
     return 0;
  }
}
```

I have tried playing around with some of the parameters of the for loops, but I have not yet succeeded.

Comment: In what graphics format do you need it? It's odd that nothing in your code tries to paint it like the pictures you've shown. Your program only does plain textual output. How is that going to end up like a picture?

Comment: I just need it printed in the console, that is all. No graphics format at all. What I have is very close, I just need to center the smaller colon blocks and rearrange the bottom ones, and that's what I do not know how to do

Comment: .... then why is your expected result a picture instead of pure text?

Comment: what do you mean by that, those two are both screenshots of the console. I don't think I'm understanding you...

Comment: You show a **picture** of the output you expect, yet you claim to expect a pure textual output. Why not put _that_ in your question? If I would try to answer your question and compare the output from my program with what you expect, how would I do that? There's a bit of reasoning behind that. Please this [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "_**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question_"

Comment: @BillBrown Why not first try to get the first two lines to line up the way you want?  Why show 20 lines of output, when you can't get the first two or three lines correct?   You wrote an entire program without testing the first couple of lines to see if the output is correct. -- *I have tried playing around with some of the parameters of the for loops* -- Start over -- get the second line to properly format itself.  Once you see how to get that line correct, then you have a base to work with to get the other lines correct.

Answer (score 1):

With every one of the console output problems for drawing asterisk triangles or boxes or whatever, it is often useful to get out a piece of graph paper and an pencil and actually draw what you want to see.

Then, consider the **negative space**:


          `-` `-` `-`    

        `{` `:` `@` `:` `}`  

          `-` `-` `-`    

        `{` `:` `:` `:` `}`  

      `{` `:` `:` `@` `:` `:` `}`

        `{` `:` `:` `:` `}`  

          `-` `-` `-`    

            `|` `/`    

            `|`      

          `\` `|`      

            `|`

Notice the blank spaces on the *left* of the graphic? The number of blank spaces to the left is directly related to the width of the centered figure.

**That is what you need to fix.**

There must be some number (zero or more) blank spaces printed on a line *before* that line’s graphic.

<sup>You may observe also that the number of blank spaces on the right don’t matter. When you are finished printing characters just print a newline and start working on the next row.</sup>

---

One other hint: You should be using **functions** to implement each one of your menu selections. Have a function that does the flower. And another to do the HELLO graphic. It is also a good idea to have a function which simply does the menu. Then your main function can look something like this:

```
int main()
{
  bool done = false;
  while (!done)
  {
    switch (menu())
    {
      case '1': hello(); break;
      case '2': flower(); break;
      case '3': done = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh my, the amount of work you put into this - and it must be considered helpful. Not that I approve giving OP anything with the question posed but your answer deserves it.